# I try to run qt-vtk-project with qt creator on linuxLite

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-14.04, vtk

When I try to build VTK project, it shows me this error:

```
class 'vtkTexture' has no member named 'SetInput' texture->SetInput(imgRedear->GetOutput());
```

Code:

```
vtkTexture* ManipFile3D::plaquageTexture(QString nameTex)
{
    vtkBMPReader* imgRedear = vtkBMPReader::New();
    imgRedear->SetFileName(nameTex);
    imgRedear->ReleaseDataFlagOn();
    imgRedear->Update();
    vtkTexture* texture = vtkTexture::New();
    texture->SetInput(imgRedear->GetOutput());
    texture->InterpolateOn();
    texture->ReleaseDataFlagOn();
    return texture;
 }
```

Comment: probably you are using vtk 6 with code written for vtk 5 http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Replacement_of_SetInput

Comment: @lib I'd make that an answer, not just a comment, because it is correct :)

Comment: @DavidDoria I'll try, but sometimes very short answers are converted to comments!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using vtk 6 (which requires SetInputData)  with code written for vtk 5 (which used SetInput) . See vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Replacement_of_SetInput